# Algebriac curves in $\mathbb P_1\times\mathbb P_1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that in $\mathbb P_2$, If we have an algebraic curve which a line intersects at one point(counting multiplicities) then it is a line, this is a direct consequence of bezout's theorem.(we are over an algebraically closed field)
Is a version of this true in $\mathbb P_1\times\mathbb P_1$?
What characterizes a curve in $\mathbb P_1\times\mathbb P_1$ such that if we fix one of the coordinates it has only one point?

Answer (score 1):

Say $\mathbf{n}:=(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)$ and $\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}}$ denotes the space $$
\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}} := \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}^{n_i}.
$$ One *defines* a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}}$ as a product $L:=L_1\times L_2\times\dots L_k$ of linear subspaces $L_i\subset\mathbb{P}^{n_i}$. Call $\dim L:=\sum_{i=1}^k \dim L_i$ the dimension of $L$ and the tuple $(\dim L_1,\dim L_2,\dots,\dim L_k)$ the format of $L$. Then the following is true.

Assume that $V\subset\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}}$ is an algebraic variety of dimension $m=\dim V$. Then, $V$ is a linear subspace if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. There exists a format $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k)$ satisfying $\sum \alpha_i = \dim\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}}-m$ such that any $L$ of format $\alpha$ intersect $V$ at a single point.
2. For every format $(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i = \dim\mathbb{P}^{\mathbf{n}}-m$ except $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k)$, a generic subspace $L$ of format $\beta$ does not intersect $V$.

In the case that $\mathbf{n}=(1,1)$, what this says is the following:

If $V\subset\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$, then there are three possibilities:

1. $V$ intersects $p\times\mathbb{P}^1$ for every $p\in\mathbb{P}^1$ at a single point but it does not intersect with $\mathbb{P}^1\times q$ for generic $q\in\mathbb{P}^1$. In this case, $V$ is linear and $V=\mathbb{P}^1\times q$ for some $q$.
2. $V$ intersects $\mathbb{P}^1\times p$ for every $p\in\mathbb{P}^1$ at a single point but it does not intersect with $q\times\mathbb{P}^1$ for generic $q\in\mathbb{P}^1$. In this case, $V$ is again linear and $V=p\times\mathbb{P}^1$ for some $q$.
3. Other cases. Then $V$ cannot be linear. For example take $V=\mathcal{Z}( x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1 )\subset\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Then, $V$ intersects with linear subspaces $p\times\mathbb{P}^1$ at a single point for every $p$ and also with linear subspaces $\mathbb{P}^1\times q$ at a single point for every $q$. But, $V$ is not linear.

Comment: What is $V$ if not linear?

Comment: @razivo Well, it can be many things. Consider the example $V=\mathcal{Z}(x_0 y_0+x_1 y_1)$ that I gave. It intersects every line at a single point but it is not itself a linear subspace. But this is very general, any other variety with this property is somehow 'equivalent' to $V$.